# How do I block a tag?

Tags: support, tags

I know this a dumb question, but StackExchange has so many great features spread about, that I find it difficult to find everything.

I searched in a few different places for "block tag" and got nothing useful.

So: How do I block a tag, so that when I browse questions, I don't see questions with a particular tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore tags via your [tag preferences](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/preferences). There will be two options: one to gray out tags which they will still be on the questions page, but be harder to see the other completely removes them from the questions page.

For more information on favoring and ignoring tags see this [FAQ page about them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do).